# Animate Swapping of Objects

Tags: animation, swiftui

I am creating a memory game.  In the first sequence all cards flip over and two cards matching cards will highlight.  All cards will flip back over and randomly chosen cards will swap positions.  I can get the values to swap using the array.swap array.shuffle functions, however I would like to animate the cards themselves swapping.  I can get the cards to flip, however switching is another story.  I have several other classes that go with this, but stackoverflow won't let me post more.  If you need more detail please let me know.

[image]

My code:

```
struct findTheCardsFourCards: View {
    @Namespace var cardAnimation: Namespace.ID
    @State var flipped = false
    @State var animate3d = false
    @State var rememberTheCard = false
    @State var timeRemaining = 15
    @State var selectYourCardsText = false
    @State var shuffleCards = false
    let showCardsFirst = 15
    let startGame = 11
    let selectYourCards = 5
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @EnvironmentObject var game: CardModel
    var rowCount = 2
    var colCount = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                ForEach(0 ..< game.cardInGame.count/rowCount){row in
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(0 ..< colCount){col in
                            CardView(card: game.cardInGame[row * rowCount + col], cardAnimation: cardAnimation, flipped: flipped, animate3d: animate3d, action: {game.cardInGame.swapAt(2, 3)})
                                .shadow(color: Color.purple, radius: highlightCards(card: game.cardInGame[row*rowCount+col]))
                                .animation(.linear)
                                .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                                    switch timeRemaining{
                                    case 14:
                                        flipped.toggle()
                                    case 8:
                                        game.cardInGame.swapAt(1,2)
                                        
                                    default: break
                                           
                                    }
                                        
                                    /*
                                    if timeRemaining > startGame {
                                        game.cardInGame[row * rowCount + col].cardSelected = true
                                        
                                    }
                                    else if timeRemaining == startGame - 1{
                                        game.cardInGame[row * rowCount + col].cardSelected = false
                                    }
                                    if timeRemaining == startGame {
                                        shuffleCards = true
                                        game.cardInGame.shuffle()
                                            
                                    }*/
                                })
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            HStack{
                Text("REMEMBER THE CARDS")
                   
            }
            .opacity(rememberTheCard ? 1.0:0.0)
            HStack{
                Text("SELECT YOUR CARDS")
            }
            .opacity(selectYourCardsText ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            //.layoutPriority(rememberTheCard ? 1.0:0.0)
            
        }
        .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
            switch timeRemaining{
            case 13:
                rememberTheCard = true
                game.flipGame.toggle()
            case 10:
                rememberTheCard = false
                game.flipGame.toggle()
            case 8:
                    game.cardInGame.swapAt(1, 3)
            case 6:
                selectYourCardsText = true
            case 3:
                selectYourCardsText = false
            
            default:
                break
            }
            /*if timeRemaining == showCardsFirst {
                rememberTheCard = true
                game.flipGame.toggle()
            }
            if timeRemaining == startGame {
                rememberTheCard = false
                game.flipGame.toggle()
            }
            if timeRemaining == startGame - 2 {
                selectYourCardsText = true
            }
            if timeRemaining == selectYourCards{
                selectYourCardsText = false
            }*/
            timeRemaining -= 1
        })
}

  func highlightCards(card: CardItem) -> CGFloat {
        //if game.cardInGame[row*rowCount+col].winningCard == true{
        if card.winningCard == true {
            if game.flipGame == true{
                return 10}}
        if card.cardSelected == true{
            return 10}
        return 0

    }
}

struct findTheCardsFourCards_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        findTheCardsFourCards()
            .environmentObject(testCardModel)
            .previewDevice("iPad Pro (9.7-inch)")
    }
}

    struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var game: CardModel
    @State private var timeRemaining = 5
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            findTheCardsFourCards()
            HStack{
                    
                Button(action: {game.flipGame.toggle()

                } ) {
                    
                    Text("Start Game")
                    
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .padding()
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .padding()
            //.onReceive(timer){ time in
                //if self.timeRemaining == 0 {
                  //      self.timeRemaining -= 1
                    //}
                //else{
                  //  game.flipGame.toggle()
               // }
                //}
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  How do I animate-switch cards?  At which line are you trying to switch cards?

Comment: Hey sorry I should have been more clear.  The swap will occur when time remaining = 8.  I have tried using onReceive with the withAnimation at the ZStack level and at the ForEach level.  Neither one seemed to work.  I thought of using geometry ready but that seems to only effect 1 object.